# Group values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 500 rows of items. I need to enter these in an application where I can enter a maximum of six items at once by creating a unique Group ID for these six items.

The items in a group share the same Store ID and date.  I have sorted and concatenated store and date so I can group it easily.  I create a unique Group ID, which is the same for up to six items that have the same date and store; the Group ID will change to the next value if fewer than six items share the same store and date.

In the example, below, the Concatenate column contains the value "100120150823" (Store ID & Date_2), repeated 10 times. For first six, I've given a Group ID as `1000`.  The remaining four get Group ID `1001`.

I need help figuring out how to calculate and fill in the Group IDs.

[image: Click here to see Example]

Comment: You need to detail this 'column' layout further? Do you mean the 'cell' as in a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1 should be the same value you then allocate a Group ID? Where is the Group ID going? More info?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, Super User is not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do.  In what manner are things grouped and how is such a group used?  Where is the group ID and how is the actual ID determined?  How do you show such a group?  Explain the variable number of columns.  What has to match in the columns (everything in the column, by row, etc.)?  This might be answerable if you include a mockup or screenshot and use the values there to explain how you produce the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is with a helper column that keeps track of the group count.  I'll assume your example is in columns A:F and will use column G for the helper.  I'll assume your column labels are in row 1 and the data starts in row 2.  Cell G2 would contain:

```
=IF(AND(E2=E1,G1<6),G1+1,1)
```

Copy that down as many rows as you need.  This compares each row to the previous row to see when the Concatenate value changes or the count reaches 6.  It works for the first data row because row 1 (the column labels), is different.

Hard code F2 as 1000.  The formula in F3 would be:

```
=IF(G3>1,F2,F2+1)
```

Copy that down as many rows as you need.  On the first row of a group (count = 1), it increments the Group ID.  Otherwise it uses the previous one.